# com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection$ClosedConnection.lambda$getClosedConnection$0(ProxyConnection.java:515) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar

Tags: java, spring, database, hikaricp

Getting below error while calling SP. Coneection established after some time when calling again getting below error

```
ERROR 1 --- [io-20001-exec-9] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Connection is closed
 ERROR 1 --- [io-20001-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not prepare statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement] with root cause java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection$ClosedConnection.lambda$getClosedConnection$0(ProxyConnection.java:515) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy107.prepareCall(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareCall(ProxyConnection.java:316) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareCall(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar!/:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar!/:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar!/:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.buildOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:384) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar!/:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.getOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:352) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar!/:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.outputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:632) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar!/:5.6.10.Final]
        at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.getResultList(ProcedureCallImpl.java:719) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar!/:5.6.10.Final]
```

```
public DataSource msDataSource() {
    DataSource dataSourceRaw = DataSourceBuilder.create().driverClassName(this.driveClassName).url(this.url).username(this.username).password(this.password).build();
    HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
    hikariConfig.setDataSource(dataSourceRaw);
    hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(this.maxActive);
    hikariConfig.setMinimumIdle(this.minIdle);
    hikariConfig.setConnectionTimeout((long)this.maxWait);
    hikariConfig.setPoolName(this.entityManagerName);
    return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
}


public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean msEntityManagerFactory(@Qualifier("msDataSource") DataSource msDataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emFactory.setDataSource(msDataSource);
    emFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{this.packageScanDir});
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect");
    emFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter);
    emFactory.setPersistenceUnitName(this.entityManagerName);
    emFactory.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
    emFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return emFactory;
}


public EntityManager mssqlEntityManager(@Qualifier("msEntityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean msEntityManagerFactory) {
    return msEntityManagerFactory.getObject().createEntityManager();
}
```